# Spring event listener with coroutines alternative

Tags: spring, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I was trying to get Spring's `@EventListener` working with coroutines/suspending functions, however, it is not supported yet. Do you know what would be a good alternative? I would need a simple message bus, the same way how the application publisher/listener is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
@EventListener
fun onEvent(message: String) {
    applicationScope.launch {
        appendLineUseCase.execute(message)
    }
}
```